# My laptop keeps restarting, what can I do to diagnose the cause?

Tags: windows-10, sleep

I have a Dell Inspiron 7591 7000 2 in 1 laptop running Windows 10. It's fairly new, about 3 months old but I notice that ever since I got it, occasionally, when it wakes up from sleep, it's completely restarted. So all the applications and documents I had are gone and it's a fresh laptop.

I've tried looking at the event viewer and the only relevant error is this

> "The previous system shutdown at 3:32:44 PM on ‎23/‎05/‎2020 was
>   unexpected."

I've tried running powercfg /sleepstudy and nothing really pops out at me.

And also powercfg /energy

I'm getting a few errors here, and different each time I run it, but I'm not sure what they mean or whether they're related.

> Platform Power Management Capabilities:ACPI _CST Object Failed
>   Validation There is a problem with the definition of the ACPI _CST
>   object on this computer. Installing the latest system firmware (BIOS)
>   may resolve this issue. Group 0 Index 0

this one happens each time

> USB Suspend:USB Device not Entering Selective Suspend This device did
>   not enter the USB Selective Suspend state. Processor power management
>   may be prevented when this USB device is not in the Selective Suspend
>   state. Note that this issue will not prevent the system from sleeping.
>   Device Name   Realtek USB GbE Family Controller Host Controller
>   ID    PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_15F0 Host Controller Location  PCI bus 7, device 0,
>   function 0 Device ID  USB\VID_0BDA&PID_8153 Port Path 4,4

this one only when the laptop is plugged into the dock so I don't think it's related

> System Availability Requests:System Required Request The device or
>   driver has made a request to prevent the system from automatically
>   entering sleep. Requesting Driver
>   Instance  INTELAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0295&SUBSYS_10280950&REV_1000\4&3ad2b48&0&0001
>   Requesting Driver Device  Realtek Audio

occasionally getting this one.

The problem does not happen all the time - maybe once every few days I'll start the laptop and realize it's restarted.

I've tried turning Hibernate on and off - it still happens.

Is there any clues here about what is going on? And if not, how should I go about figuring out what's wrong?

Is this likely to be a software / driver's type issue or could it be a hardware issue?

Comment: If you're not on the latest firmware version, get there first. The release notes for [Version 1.4.0, 1.4.0](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=3cm9y&oscode=wt64a&productcode=inspiron-15-7591-2-in-1-laptop) indicate a patch related to power event logs so perhaps there's also this issue that's patched if it's a firmware bug. Maybe downgrade a level in case it was introduced too with the latest version maybe. Otherwise, run `cmd` as admin and then run `powercfg –restoredefaultschemes`. Afterwards, run `sfc /scannow` and let that finish and then reboot.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT yes it is running v1.4.0 - all drivers and BIOS are at the latest version as far as windows update and dell update is concerned

Comment: ran the sfc and returned "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations."

Comment: If you go to Power Management in Control Panel, in the advanced settings for your power plan of choice, there should be one or several options regarding USB. One would be to allow or disallow USB ports to interrupt sleep when an external input occurs. That's where I'd look first, because the error message you get mentions that your PC was trying to go to sleep but was interrupted by a USB device.